# How to parse the xml file part by part ?

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application. In that I am getting 500 to 600 questions via xml. But if I parse the total file at one time it takes a lot of time.

So I want to parse the xml file part by part to save the time duration.That means first I parse the xml file for first three questions and after showing those three , I can do the parsing for next three ones and so on.

But how can I stop the parsing after getting the three questions ?

If anybody knows any other approach to do the parsing fast then please tell me. Btw I am using `TBXML` for parsing.

Comment: show some example from your question xml

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  I hope it'll help you:

```
-(void) loadXML:(NSString *)urlStr
{
    NSData  *data   = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    parser          = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];
}

/****
e.g.
<name>Romit</name>
**/
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    // method to make operation when element stated. <name>
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    // you get all data in this delegate method. from string variable.
    // name value
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
   // make operation when element finished.
  //</name>
}
```

Comment: Thank you.But i know how to do the xml parsing and delegate methods for that class.I need to do the parsing a big file very fastly or do the parsing parts by parts.

Comment: what do you use to display data?

Comment: I can store that data into arrays and display on Labels

Comment: then i think you should use table view if your data is larger.

Comment: In which control i can display that's not a problem.I want to do the parsing very fastly or do the parsing parts by parts.So pleas etell me if you know any of these two ways..

Comment: you have use Thread, but your data is heavy then its obviously takes time. then you should display loader.

Comment: OK.U know how to do the parsing Parts by parts?

Comment: yes my friend this is the only way if you want to use NSXmlParse, otherwise you can use thirdparty. but NSXmlParser is SAX parser so it better & faster.

Comment: If i take nsthread and give priority as high for that nsthread then is there any chance to get the data fast.